# Which algebraic statements are preserved by isomorphisms?

Tags: group-theory, logic, group-isomorphism

I am asking a general question. Suppose two groups $(G, \circ)$ and $(H, \star)$ are isomorphic. Then as is often stated, "algebraic statements" which hold for $(G, \circ)$ also hold for $(H, \star)$.

**Question:** Exactly what "algebraic statements" are preserved?

I know that the statement, say for $G$, can only contain the the following:

1. "objects:" $G$, $e_G$ and variables
2. "relations:" $=$, $\in$
3. "functions:" $^{-1}$ (inverse), $\circ$

Is there some precise way to characterize the statements, or is the above list all?

Comment: No your list is incomplete.
All those properties that can be formulated in the language of the group operation are preserved. For example, such a property. Each element is the square of some element. Or a group has a subgroup of index 2 and so on.

Comment: @kabenyuk But since I have included $\circ$, won't it be expressible like this:
$\forall x\in G$, $\exists y\in G$ such that $x = y\circ y$?

Comment: @kabenyuk oh I see what you mean! You mean that my statement can also include properties that can be described using my list, right?
But if so, then my list is sufficient, isn't it?

Comment: If it is interpreted in such an expansive sense, then of course it is enough. It includes properties such as: abelian, simple, solvable, periodic, torsion-free, cyclic, and so on.

Comment: In an algebraic statement as defined above, is it possible to use $\in$ or $G$ outside of the bound quantifier construction $\forall x \in G \mathop. \varphi$ (where $\varphi$ is a well-formed formula) (and likewise for $\exists$)?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet I guess yes. Trivial example: $G = G$. Another: $e\in G$.

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with category theory, then there is a fairly straightforward way to get a broad class of isomorphism-invariant properties.

Recall that a category has a class of objects and, for any two objects $A$ and $B$, a set of morphisms $A \to B$ between these objects.

The finitary statements that can be made about a category can be classified as statements in the language of category theory. In the language of category theory, there is a type of objects and for any objects $A, B$, a type of arrows $A \to B$. Statements in the language of category theory are defined inductively as all statements of the form

- $f = g$ where $f, g$ are both arrow terms $A \to B$ for some objects $A, B$
- For any statements in the language of category theory, any combination of these statements using the logical operators $\land, \lor, \neg, \implies, \top, \bot$
- For any statement in the language of category theory $P(f)$ where $f$ has type $A \to B$, the statements $\forall f : A \to B, P(f)$ and $\exists f : A \to B, P(f)$
- For any statement in the language of category theory $P(A)$ where $A$ has object type, the statements $\forall A, P(A)$ and $\forall B, P(B)$

Notice the critical bit is in the propositions of the form $f = g$. We CANNOT compare two objects for equality, and we can ONLY compare two arrows for equality when they have the same type. So we have excluded statements like $G_1 = G_2$ when we are discussing groups $G_1$ and $G_2$.

Now consider the category of sets. Consider a statement $P(G, +)$ in the language of category theory, where $+ : G^2 \to G$.

Given two isomorphic groups $(G_1, +_1), (G_2, +_2)$, one can always prove the statement $P(G_1, +_1) \iff P(G_2, +_2)$.

So any statement that can be stated (1) in the language of the category of sets and (2) only in terms of the group operator, the statement is preserved by isomorphism.

Let's ask ourselves what kinds of statements can be made in the language of category theory.

Can we discuss elements of a set $A$ in the language of category theory? Yes. Let $1$ be a fixed 1-element set. Then elements of $A$ correspond exactly to functions $1 \to A$. Thus, we can compare two elements to equality, apply a function to an element, and quantify over all the elements in a set.

Can we discuss subsets of a set $A$ in the language of category theory? Yes. Rather than discussing the subsets themselves, we can discuss injective functions $f : B \to A$. Note that injective functions into a set $A$ correspond in a canonical way to subsets of $A$.

Can we discuss things like the group having finite order in the language of category theory? Yes. It turns out that we can write "$A$ is finite" in the language of category theory.

Can we discuss things like inverses and the identity element? Yes. The identity element is the unique element $e : 1 \to G$ such that for all elements $x : 1 \to G$, $e + x = x + e = x$. So we can specify the identity element using the language of category theory together with the axioms of a group. We can do the same with inverses.

In fact, the language of category theory is so broad that it's possible to come up with a set theory solely based in the language of category theory that is exactly as powerful as normal set theory. If you take a categorical set theory to be your foundation, then literally every statement you can make about a given group is preserved under isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for your time to write which I definitely believe is a fantastic answer. however, I have no background in category theory. Can you provide point me to some "crash course" just sufficient to understand what you've written?

Comment: @Atom Let's say that instead of talking about set theory in terms of sets and elements of sets, we only discuss set theory in terms of sets and functions between sets. We also maintain the discipline of only asking whether two things are equal if they are both functions with the same domain and codomain. Any property that can be phrased in this way is always preserved under isomorphism. In fact, you can show that set theory formulated in this way is just as strong as ordinary set theory formulated in terms of elements.

Comment: Thanks for you introduction of CT. You briefly mentioned CT can describe finiteness, while a major "defect" (feature) of first order logic is $\forall$ quantifier's inability to describe finiteness as exemplified from the compactness and L-S theorems. Can you elaborate the tricks CT employ to achieve so?

Comment: @MarkSaving I'm trying my best to understand whatever you've written. A few questions: (i) Are morphisms and arrows same? (The second paragraph.) (ii) Between two objects $A$ and $B$ of a category, can there by more than one arrow? If so, can there be more than one type of arrows for the same $A$ and $B$?

Comment: (iii) In the fifth paragraph, should $+\colon G^2\to G$ be interpreted as an arrow or a function?

Comment: @mohottnad The trick is that since we can quantify over all "subsets" of a given set, we actually get second-order (or even higher-order) logic. So we can define "$X$ is finite" as "there exists a well-order on $X + 1$ such that every element of $X + 1$ is either a successor or the least element".

Comment: @Atom Arrows are functions. When we discuss "the category of sets", the arrows are functions.

Comment: @Atom (i) The terms "morphism" and "arrow" are the same. (ii) Yes, there can be many arrows. When we discuss "the category of sets", the objects of this category are sets, and the arrows of this category $A \to B$ are functions between $A$ and $B$. So there are infinitely many arrows $1 \to \mathbb{N}$, for example, where $1$ is a 1-element set. If you only consider the case where there's at most one arrow between two objects, you are essentially considering the theory of pre-orders. (iii) $+ : \mathbb{G}^2 \to G$ is an arrow, which is a function.

Comment: @MarkSaving Thanks for your answers. Another one: (iv) According to the first item of your bulleted list, will all the functions (arrows) $1\to\mathbb N$ be equal since they start and end at the same sets? Or do we use the equality of functions here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129444/discussion-between-mark-saving-and-atom).